# Use a specific instance of a class inside an isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, service-locator

I am using an isolate through the `compute()` method to fetch, parse and sort datas from an API (around 10k entries).

My method `getAllCards()` is defined inside a class `YgoProRepositoryImpl` which has an instance of my remote datasource class `YgoProRemoteDataSource` it is in this class that the method to call my API is defined (it is a simple GET request).

### Code Sample

`ygopro_repository_impl.dart`:

```dart
class YgoProRepositoryImpl implements YgoProRepository {
  final YgoProRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;

  // ...

  YgoProRepositoryImpl({
    required this.remoteDataSource,
    // ...
  });

  // ...

  static Future<List<YgoCard>> _fetchCards(_) async {
    // As I'm inside an isolate I need to re-setup my locator
    setupLocator();
    final cards = await sl<YgoProRemoteDataSource>()
        .getCardInfo(GetCardInfoRequest(misc: true));
    cards.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    return cards;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getAllCards() async {
    final cards = await compute(_fetchCards, null);
    return cards;
  }

  // ...
}
```

`service_locator.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

import 'data/api/api.dart';
import 'data/datasources/remote/ygopro_remote_data_source.dart';
import 'data/repository/ygopro_repository_impl.dart';
import 'domain/repository/ygopro_repository.dart';

final sl = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  // ...

  _configDomain();
  _configData();

  // ...

  _configExternal();
}

void _configDomain() {
  //! Domain
  
  // ...

  // Repository
  sl.registerLazySingleton<YgoProRepository>(
    () => YgoProRepositoryImpl(
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
      // ...
    ),
  );
}

void _configData() {
  //! Data
  // Data sources
  sl.registerLazySingleton<YgoProRemoteDataSource>(
    () => YgoProRemoteDataSourceImpl(sl<RemoteClient>()),
  );

  // ...
}

void _configExternal() {
  //! External
  sl.registerLazySingleton<RemoteClient>(() => DioClient());
  
  // ...
}
```

The code is working properly but `getAllCards()` is not testable as I cannot inject a mocked class of `YgoProRemoteDataSource` inside my isolate because it will always get a reference from my service locator.

How can I do to not rely on my service locator to inject `YgoProRemoteDataSource` inside my isolate and make `getAllCards()` testable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a more serious attempt, please see the repo: https://github.com/maxim-saplin/compute_sl_test_sample

Essentially with the current state of affairs with Flutter/Dart you can't pass neither closures nor classes containing closures across isolates boundaries (yet that might change when newer features in Dart land Flutter https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46623#issuecomment-916161528). That means there's no way you can pass service locator (which contains closures) or trick the isolate to instantiate a test version of locator via closure IF you don't want any test code to be part of the release build. Yet you can easily pass data source instance to isolate to be used at its entry point as a param.

Beside, I don't think asking isolate to rebuild the entire service locator makes sense. The whole idea behind compute() is to create a short leaving isolate, run the computation, return the result and terminate the isolate. Initialising the locator is an overhead which is better to be avoided. Besides it seems the whole concept of compute() is being as isolated from the rest of the app as possible.

You can clone the repo and run the tests. Few words about the sample:

- Based on Flutter counter starter app
- `lib/classes.dart` recreates the code snippet you provided
- `test/widget_test.dart` verifies that `YgoProRepositoryImpl` is working fine with isolate running fake version of data source
- `YgoProRemoteDataSourceImpl` mimics real implementation and is located at classes.dart and `YgoProRemoteDataSourceFake` mimics test version
- Running isolates under flutter_test requires wrapping test body in `tester.runAsync()` in order to have real time async execution (rather than fake async used by default by tests and relying on pumping to progress test time). Running tests in this mode can be slow (there's actual 0.5 second wait), structuring the tests in a way when compute() is not used or tested not in many tests is reasonable

`classes.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

final sl = GetIt.instance;

class YgoCard {
  YgoCard(this.name);

  final String name;
}

abstract class YgoProRemoteDataSource {
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getCardInfo();
}

class YgoProRemoteDataSourceImpl extends YgoProRemoteDataSource {
  @override
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getCardInfo() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero,
        () => List.generate(5, (index) => YgoCard("Impl $index")));
  }
}

abstract class YgoProRepository {
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getAllCards();
}

class YgoProRepositoryImpl implements YgoProRepository {
  final YgoProRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;

  YgoProRepositoryImpl({
    required this.remoteDataSource,
  });

  static Future<List<YgoCard>> _fetchCards(
      YgoProRemoteDataSource dataSource) async {
    final cards = await dataSource.getCardInfo();
    cards.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    return cards;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getAllCards() async {
    final cards = await compute(_fetchCards, remoteDataSource);
    return cards;
  }
}

void setupLocator() {
  sl.registerLazySingleton<YgoProRepository>(
    () => YgoProRepositoryImpl(
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton<YgoProRemoteDataSource>(
    () => YgoProRemoteDataSourceImpl(),
  );
}
```

`widget_test.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:test_sample/classes.dart';

import 'package:test_sample/main.dart';

void main() {
  setUpAll(() async {
    setupFakeLocator();
  });

  testWidgets('Test mocked data source', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Wrapping with runAync() is required to have real async in place
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
      // Let the isolate spawned by compute() complete, Debug run might require longer wait
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.text('Fake 9'), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}

class YgoProRemoteDataSourceFake extends YgoProRemoteDataSource {
  @override
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getCardInfo() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero,
        () => List.generate(10, (index) => YgoCard("Fake $index")));
  }
}

void setupFakeLocator() {
  sl.registerLazySingleton<YgoProRepository>(
    () => YgoProRepositoryImpl(
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton<YgoProRemoteDataSource>(
    () => YgoProRemoteDataSourceFake(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer. I was not able to apply the principles from your example as the issue with my project was that I was executing the GET request inside my isolate through `getCardInfo` which was the cause of my isolate failing. In the end I've decided to move my call to `compute` directly inside the method `getCardInfo` to only manage the parsing of my response. I will still valid your answer as it helped me understand what was wrong in my implementation.

Comment: Also to ensure your answer does not depend too much on the link to your repo could you edit it to add some code snippets.

Comment: Glad it helped! Added code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to test the `getCards()` function?
What are you really testing there? That `compute` works, sure hope the Dart SDK team has a test for this.

That leaves `_fetchCards()`, and `setupLocator()` doesn't need to be tested either, it is precondition for your test-logic. You want to change the setup for the test anyways.

So what you actually want to test is the fetching & sorting. Restructure this into a testable static function and setup your locator beforehand. Put a `@visibleForTesting` annotation on it.

And on a side-note, depending on how much you bind in your service locator, this could be huge overhead for just using the one repository afterwards.

Example:

```dart
  static Future<List<YgoCard>> _fetchCards(_) async {
    // As I'm inside an isolate I need to re-setup my locator
    setupLocator();
    return reallyFetchCards();
  }

  @visibleForTesting
  static Future<List<YgoCard>> reallyFetchCards() async {
    final cards = await sl<YgoProRemoteDataSource>()
        .getCardInfo(GetCardInfoRequest(misc: true));
    cards.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    return cards;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getAllCards() async {
    final cards = await compute(_fetchCards, null);
    return cards;
  }
```

Test:

```dart
// Setup SL and datasource
...

final cards = await YgoProRepositoryImpl.reallyFetchCrads();

// Expect stuff
```

Comment: Good point, from unit testing perspective it makes sense to keep the compute() call beyond the scope of testing. 

Yet from integration testing perspective it makes sense to try and test how a certain code behaves within spawned isolates which frankly speaking are tricky. E.g. the spawned isolate might miss Flutter initialisations, say a call to ensureInitialized()

Besides, there can be breaking changes and bugs in Dart isolates ;) E.g. Flutter 2.5.0 comes with such changes: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46754 OR https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47672

Comment: Basically my test is to check that the method `getCardInfo` is correctly called and ensure that `getAllCards` returns me a sorted list of `YgoCard`. So yes theoretically I don't need to directly test `_fetchCards()` and `setupLocator()` but I need to be able to fake the data returned by `getCardInfo` which I am usually doing by mocking the class `YgoProRemoteDataSource` but my locator cannot inject the mocked class so I can't return consistent data for my test. Could you please elaborate what you have in mind by "testable static function and setup your locator beforehand" ?

Comment: Updated with an example

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have two options, either inject the dependencies needed for `static Future<List<YgoCard>> _fetchCards(_) async` via parameters, or mock the object in the locator itself. I would go for the fist option, and have something like :

```
  static Future<List<YgoCard>> _fetchCards(_,YgoProRemoteDataSource remote) async {
    // No need to set up locator as you passed the needed dependencies
    // setupLocator();
    final cards = await remote
        .getCardInfo(GetCardInfoRequest(misc: true));
    cards.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    return cards;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<YgoCard>> getAllCards() async {
    final cards = await compute(_fetchCards, null);
    return cards;
  }
```

#### Edit

just updated the answer as its easier to edit this here than in the comments...

Hmm, the only workaround that I can think of is to pass the setupLocator() function as an argument to the class YgoProRepositoryImpl :

```
final Function setupLocator;
  YgoProRepositoryImpl({
    required this.remoteDataSource,
required this.setupLocator;
    // ...
  });
```

This way you could pass a mock that sets up your mock classes or the real `setupLocator` of your `service_locator.dart`. This might not be to elegant. But it should make it testable as now you can mock the setup and its not hardcoded in the function

Comment: Already tried, I got a `Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message` exception. And injecting my mocked classes directly in the service locator would make it dependant on generated classes which should only be exposed for unit tests.

Comment: It is because you cannot pass any class inside an isolate, supported classes are defined in the documentation of `SendPort.send`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity but unfortunately your edit would not work either, you cannot pass a `Function` as an argument to an isolate as explained in the documentation I've linked.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting to pass it to the isolate/compute. but to the class in which that method is. So instead of calling setupLocator from your `service_locator.dart` you call the one you injected in through the  `YgoProRepositoryImpl` constructor.

Comment: Yes I've understood that but I will need to calle setupLocator inside my isolate but as the method executed by an isolate needs to be a static or a top-level function I will have to pass the reference to setupLocator as an argument at some point.

Comment: Yikes, totally forgot about the `static` , sorry 